# Cell note in jxls template is not deleted

Tags: spring, apache-poi, jxls

```
PoiTransformer transformer = PoiTransformer.createTransformer(is, os);
        AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XlsCommentAreaBuilder(transformer, false);
        List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();

        int curSheetSize = 3;
        for(int i = 1; i < 1; i++) {
            Area mainArea = xlsAreaList.get(i);
            Area loopArea = mainArea.getCommandDataList().get(0).getCommand().getAreaList().get(0);
            loopArea.addAreaListener(new JxlsAreaListener(transformer, i));

            switch (i) {
                case 1 :
                    mainArea.applyAt(new CellRef("KOR!A1"), context);
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    mainArea.applyAt(new CellRef("JPN!A1"), context);                       
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    mainArea.applyAt(new CellRef("FRA!A1"), context);
                    break;
                case 4 :
                    mainArea.applyAt(new CellRef("AUS!A1"), context);
                    break;
                case 5 :
                    mainArea.applyAt(new CellRef("UK!A1"), context);
                    break;
                case 6 :
                    mainArea.applyAt(new CellRef("CAN!A1"), context);
                    break;
                case 7 :
                    mainArea.applyAt(new CellRef("MEX!A1"), context);
                    break;
            }

            mainArea.processFormulas();
        }

       transformer.write();

        is.close();
        os.close();
```

I hope the memo is deleted in the Excel file made from template. please.

is templete
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W24eF.png)

is Files created from templates
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mCh0.png)